# A set of functions generating another set of functions.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have read this fact being used in a book, but I don't quite see why it is true, can you please help me?

Assume you have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the class of funtioncs $\mathbb{R}\times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes \mathcal{A}$ -measurable. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the set of functions of the form $f(x)X(\omega)$ where $f$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable and $X$ is a random variable, hence $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.  Let $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ be the smallest collection of sets of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes \mathcal{A}$ such that every function in $\mathcal{E}$ is $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$-measurable. It is then stated(indirectly) that $\sigma(\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes \mathcal{A}$.

Is the property as stated here true? If yes, is there an easy way to show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{B}\otimes \mathcal{A} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E})$, since for each measurable rectangle $B \times A \in \mathcal{B}\otimes \mathcal{A}$, $\mathbb{1}_B\mathbb{1}_A$ is measurable, hence $B \times A \in \sigma(\mathcal{E})$, and $\mathcal{B}\otimes \mathcal{A}$ is the smallest $\sigma-$algebra containing the measurable rectangles. The other inclusion is clear from the definition.

Comment: Thank you very much!